# Django permission denied to delete comment

Tags: python, django

i have a problem with my blog comment delete. It works properly when the user is superuser, but keep getting "django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied
[07/Jan/2022 01:47:09] "GET /blog/comentario/eliminar/6/ HTTP/1.1" 403 135" when the user is comment autor but no superuser.

here is my code:

Model.

```
class BlogComentario(models.Model):

post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="comentarios")
nombre = models.ForeignKey(Usuario,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
contenido = models.TextField(max_length=500)
publicado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publicado',)
    db_table= "blog_comentario"

def __str__(self):
    return f"comentado por {self.nombre}"
```

view

```
class ComentarioEliminar(UserPassesTestMixin,DeleteView):
template_name = 'Blog/Comentarios/comentario_eliminar.html'
model = BlogComentario

def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
    return reverse('blog:blog_inicio')
    
def test_func(self):
    obj = self.get_object()
    return obj.nombre == self.request.user or self.request.user.is_superuser
```

Comment: The user which you use to connect to db has delete privileges on db?

Comment: @Shiv i guess so, if i dont use the test_func in the view i can delete the comments with any user, the problem is when i try to let only comment autor delete. I dont know if i am wrong getting the object.nombre(author), because it works in other class with userpassestest trying to delete posts and not comments.

Comment: I don't see any requirement that the user needs to be authenticated to access this view (LoginRequiredMixin e.g.) . Are you sure the self.request.user is actually an authenticated user and not just a AnonymousUser?

Comment: @Matt i forget to use the loginrequiredMixin, but anyway whas testing with a user logged in, without being a superuser it keeps returning that permission error

Comment: Then the only explanation I can think of is that `obj.nombre == self.request.user` returns False.

Comment: @Matt idk what happened, just test the same code today and now it works, django things i suppose (?. Thanks for your help